# Knapsack with Specific Item Requirements

Tags: r, knapsack-problem

I have a knapsack problem that has a weight capacity and a required combination of items. Here's the set up: The goal is to maximize utility (p) when the sum of the weights (w) is capped at 5000, but the knapsack can only contain 8 items and there are specific requirements for the items. The Knapsack must contain the following combination of 5 unique items:

```
Item_1 = Type_1

Item_2 = Type_2

Item_3 = Type_3

Item_4 = Type_4

Item_5 = Type_5

Item_6 = Type_1 or Type_2

Item_7 = Type_3 or Type_4

Item_8 = Type_1 or Type_2 or Type_3 or Type_4 of Type_5
```

I have been using `lpSolve` in R and have the following code:

---

```
library(lpSolve)

p <- c(40,50,30,20,10,20,15,20,35,40)

w <-c(100,200,300,400,500,400,300,300,400,200)

cap<-5000

exact.num.elt <- 8

mod<-lp(direction="max",objective.in=p,
const.mat= rbind(w,rep(1, length(p))),const.dir=c("<=","="),const.rhs=c(cap,exact.num.elt),all.bin=TRUE)

which(mod$solution>=0.999)
```

---

This does not account for the combination requirements. Is there a way I can account for this? I would also like to see the top 20 combinations for comparison.